# How to check for a specific word in the URL before running script?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have the current script to amend a link in the URL bar

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    location.replace(location.href.replace("www.reddit.com", "old.reddit.com"));
})();
```

I'd want it to check if the URL has the word "old" before running the remainder of the script. How do I do this?

Comment: See also `document-start` as shown in at least one answer to the duplicate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the index of the word `old` by considering the URL as a normal string.

```
if(location.href.indexOf('old') > -1) {
  // do something
}
```

It is simple as that.